# C++ Call virtual method of child class instead of base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

I have a base class `Feature`

**feature.h**

```
#ifndef FEATURE_H   
#define FEATURE_H

#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

template <class T> class Feature
{
public:
    virtual map<string, double> calculate(T input)
    {
        map<string, double> empty;

        return empty;
    }
};

#endif FEATURE_H
```

And a child class `AvgSentenceLength`

**avgSentenceLength.h**

```
#include "text.h"
#include "feature.h"

class AvgSentenceLength : public Feature<Text>
{
public:
    map<string, double> calculate(Text text);
};
```

I try to call `calculate` method from another file using `AvgSentenceLength` object, not directly but still:

```
map<int, Feature<Text>> features;
AvgSentenceLength avgSentenceLength;
features.insert(pair<int, Feature<Text>>(1, avgSentenceLength));

map<string, double> featuresValues;
featuresValues = features.at(1).calculate(text);
```

I want to call `calculate` method of the child class, but it calls `calculate` method of the base class. I can't use pure virtual function in the base class because it is necessary to create objects of this class.

Comment: though it doesn't seem to be the issue here, in C++11 it helps to add a trailing `override` when overriding a base class's virtual function, if you mess up and accidentally introduce a new function via a typo in the name or a different argument type, the compiler will emit an error

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `map<int, Feature<Text>>` to `map<int, Feature<Text>*>`. To Call polymorphic function through its base you need a level of indirection such as a pointer or a reference.

Answer (score 1):

simply add a pointer`*` to this line:`map<int, Feature<Text>> features`

so that its like this:  `map<int, Feature<Text>*> features`.